# Bash Scripting: when trying to read 3 lines at a time, input line gets skipped in between

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to split video by chapters by reading chapter details from text file, storing each values in a variable and passing those to ffmpeg. After splitting some chapters, start time and end time gets mixed with chapter title.

Below is the script

```
#1 /bin/bash

file=$(echo "$1" | awk -F '.' '{print $(NF-1)}')
ext=$(echo "$1" | awk -F '.' '{print $(NF)}')
ffprobe -show_chapters "$1" | grep -i 'id=\|start_time\|end_time\|title' > chapters.txt
rm temp.txt
while read chapter_id; do
    read start_time
    read end_time
    read chapter_title
    id=$(echo "$chapter_id" | awk -F '=' '{print $(NF)}')
    st=$(echo "$start_time" | awk -F '=' '{print $(NF)}')
    en=$(echo "$end_time" | awk -F '=' '{print $(NF)}')
    title=$(echo "$chapter_title" | awk -F '=' '{print $(NF)}')
    echo "id=$id" >> temp.txt
    echo "start=$id" >> temp.txt
    echo "end=$en" >> temp.txt
    echo "title=$title" >> temp.txt
    echo "------" >> temp.txt
    ffmpeg -ss "$st" -to "$en" -y -i "$1" -c copy "$file-$id-$title.$ext"
done < chapters.txt
```

Comment: sample chapters.txt file

`id=1
start_time=0.000000
end_time=15.000000
TAG:title=Introduction
id=2
start_time=15.000000
end_time=272.000000
TAG:title=Course Overview`

sample temp.txt

`id=1
start=1
end=15.000000
title=Introduction
------
id=2
start=2
end=272.000000
title=Course Overview
------
id=3
start=3
end=690.000000
title=Development Tools
------
id=690.000000
start=690.000000
end=C compiler support
title=5
------
id=857.000000
start=857.000000
end=Installing the compilers
title=6`

Comment: `ffmpeg` is likely eating your input.  Look for topics on how to avoid that.

Comment: You also don't need to use `rm`.  Simply open `temp.txt` for writing in the `while` command body using a specific file descriptor and then use `echo ... >&<the_file_descriptor>`.  Also look for topics about it.

Comment: `while read chapter_id; do
    read start_time
    read end_time
    read chapter_title` that's 4 reads `sample chapters.txt file` Please edit your post and add the sample to the post.

Comment: BTW, all the `awk` runs are needless. `id=${chapter_id##*=}` is **far** faster.

Comment: This is also [BashFAQ #89](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089).

Comment: (similarly, `file=${1%.*}` and `ext=${1##*.}`; mind, you might want to check for and handle the case where the filename has no dots in it at all).

Comment: ...you could also get rid of `chapters.txt`, replacing `<chapters.txt` with `< <(ffmpeg -show_chapters "$1" | grep ...)`. I'd think seriously about doing something similar to eliminate `temp.txt` as well outright, though we'd need to know what you're using it for to figure out details.